# Работа с методом onResume()

Tags: java, android

Хотелось бы узнать почему выдает ошибку в последних строках, а именно в слове `mBanner`. Вот `java` код:

```
package com.project1.project1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mBanner = (AWView) findViewById(R.id.bvBannerMain);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mBanner.request('25',”слово1,слово2”);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не объявлена на уровне класса сия переменная. Просто добавьте её в тело класса:

```
AWView mBanner;
```

Comment: Таким образом?:                                                                                                             protected void onResume()
    { AWView mBanner;
        super.onResume();
        mBanner.request('25',”слово1,слово2”);
    }

Comment: @Вячеслав,  Нет, так вы поместите объявление переменной в тело метода. Вам же надо поместить его в тело класса. Т.е. после первой открывающейся фигурной скобки в файле.

Comment: Ок, ошибка пропала, но в инструкции, где я взял этот код, сказано что необходима вот эта строка: import ru.ideast.adwired.AWView; сразу после package com.project1.project1;  Но символ  ru не распознается системой и отмечается красным. Не знаю как решать эту проблему, может есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: @Вячеслав, скорее всего у вас библиотека не подключена. Та коя содержит класс AWView

Comment: Имеете ввиду подключить библиотеки из SDK менеджера?

Comment: @Вячеслав, судя по всему это сторонняя библиотека и её в СДКМенеджере нет. Инструкция по её подключению должна быть там же, где лежат её файлы.